# OpenGL - Make Z face up

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, glm-math, perspective

(See image at bottom)

Most tutorials for OpenGL use a first person view and Y faces upwards.

However, I am trying to have the camera focus on a specific point and have z face upwards (like CAD software)

To achieve this, I have tried to swap Y and Z to calculate the position:

```
pos.x = cos(m_Yaw) * cos(m_Pitch);
pos.y = sin(m_Yaw) * cos(m_Pitch); // This was Z
pos.z = sin(m_Pitch);              // This was Y

m_Position = (m_Zoom * pos) + m_Centre;
```

The Up vector is then calculated:

```
m_WorldUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

m_Front = glm::normalize(pos);
m_Right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(m_Front, m_WorldUp));
m_Up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(m_Right, m_Front));
```

The View Matrix is calculated with:

```
m_ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(m_Position, m_Centre, m_Up);
```

The Projection Matrix is calculated with (although I don't think this is relavant):

```
m_ProjMatrix = glm::perspective(m_FOV, m_ScreenW / m_ScreenH, m_Near, m_Far);
```

When m_Centre is not at the origin, it can look distorted at certain angles:
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdzNi.png)

If you rotate your head 90 degrees, this seems to look correct...

What can I do differently?

Comment: No idea what you mean by "it can look distorted" at that image. It is just a perspective projection of a cube.

Comment: @derhass the vertical line on the right of the cube should be shorter than than the vertical line in the centre. If you rotate your head 90 degrees CCW, you will notice it looks correct

Comment: No idea what issue you have. Also not sure what you mean by "vertical lines" but the right edge of the cube _is_ shorter than the center line of the front face of the cube. Btw, the perspective distortion is invariant to rotations around your view axis, it is simply impossible that a perspective distortion is "wrong" for one head orientation (around the view axis), but "right" for another. The only distortions you could get there would be a wrong aspect ratio.